# How can I prevent Android emulator from crashing my laptop?

Tags: android

I have tried experimenting with a few variables (starting from within/outside Eclipse, different SDK versions, different screen resolutions) and can't find a consistent reason that the Android emulator is crashing on my laptop running Ubuntu 11.10. When it does, it shuts down my machine.

Is there anything I can do to sandbox the emulator process so that if it does crash, it doesn't take everything else with it?

Answer (score -1):

You can decrease its size and disable some functionality that you won't be needing.

Comment: How would one go about doing that?